# Get Android source code

Tags: android, android-source

I want know if I can or when I can open the website : http://android.git.kernel.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/a94fb5bd4b47ed1a).

kernel.org was hacked a while ago. You can download Android source now from mirror https://github.com/android.

Comment: Wow,Thank you so much!But I really get shocked when knowing the answer is "hacked". :-)

Answer (score 0):

Android Ice cream (whatever version number that ends up being), the next one after honeycomb, will be open source. Honeycomb will be depreciated at that point and not made open source.

Answer (score 0):

Android 3 was is a closed source piece of software and as such is unable to be downloaded or checked publicly.

Answer (score 0):

There's no open source for v3.x :)